# Booting GRUB from the network: can't find grub.cfg?

Tags: grub2, pxe

I am working on the following setup:

- A DHCP server on a Debian 11 server, *vogon* (192.168.50.9)
- A TFTP server on a Debian 12 server *zorn* (192.168.50.111)
- A client, currently in a VirtualBox VM

The relevant config on *vogon*:

```
subnet 192.168.50.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.50.10 192.168.50.190;
  option routers 192.168.50.1;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.50.255;
  option boot-size 8208;
  next-server 192.168.50.111;
  option tftp-server-address 192.168.50.111;
  option bootfile-name "/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/core.efi";
  filename "/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/core.efi";
}
```

On *zorn* I used grub-mknetdir to create the grub directory, with the following grub.cfg:

```
# ll /srv/tftp/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/*cfg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 291 Jun 30 09:52 /srv/tftp/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/grub.cfg
# cat /srv/tftp/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/*cfg
menuentry 'Boot Debian 12' {
  set background_color=black
  linux /debian12/boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-9-amd64 console=tty0 console=ttyS0 ip=dhcp root=/dev/nfs ro nfsroot=192.168.50.111:/image/debian12,vers=3,nolock panic=60 ipv6.disable=1 rootwait
  initrd /debian12/boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-9-amd64
}
```

I have configured the VM client to send output on COM1/ttyS0 to a file, *ttyS0.log*. When I start the VM, it downloads the boot loader, *core.efi*, and then ends up in the GRUB shell. The log file doesn't show anything more enlightening. It looks like the *grub.cfg* simply isn't found; in fact, playing around a bit with the GRUB command line, it seems the *(tftp)* device isn't detected at all:

```
grub> ls (tftp)
Device tftp:
grub> ls (tftp,192.168.50.111)
        Partition tftp,192.168.50.111:
grub>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Note that `tftp` doesn't support listing files, so that output from the grub `ls` command is probably expected. What do you see in the logs on zorn? Or alternately, what do you see if you capture the tftp session using `tcpdump`?

Comment: @larsks I figured out what the problem was, namely that I am a bit dense. I've added an answer - I discovered how to see what GRUB was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

So, the short answer is: the `grub.cfg` has to be in `boot/grub/` under `tftp`'s work directory - usually `/srv/tftp`, but the value can be found in `/etc/default/tftp` or by looking at the running process:

```
# ps -ef | grep tftp
root       16120       1  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/in.tftpd --listen --user tftp --address :69 -vv -s /srv/tftp
```

When you boot via PXE, files get downloaded via TFTP; unfortunately on my system (Debian 12) the tftp daemon doesn't log to `/var/log/syslog`, but as I discovered, it logs to the journal log, so to see the messages:

```
# journalctl | grep tftpd
...
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16382]: RRQ from 192.168.50.93 filename /boot/grub/grub.cfg-01-08-00-27-ae-a4-19
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16382]: sending NAK (1, File not found) to 192.168.50.93
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16383]: RRQ from 192.168.50.93 filename /boot/grub/grub.cfg-C0A8325D
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16383]: sending NAK (1, File not found) to 192.168.50.93
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16384]: RRQ from 192.168.50.93 filename /boot/grub/grub.cfg-C0A8325
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16384]: sending NAK (1, File not found) to 192.168.50.93
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16385]: RRQ from 192.168.50.93 filename /boot/grub/grub.cfg-C0A832
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16385]: sending NAK (1, File not found) to 192.168.50.93
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16386]: RRQ from 192.168.50.93 filename /boot/grub/grub.cfg-C0A83
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16386]: sending NAK (1, File not found) to 192.168.50.93
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16387]: RRQ from 192.168.50.93 filename /boot/grub/grub.cfg-C0A8
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16387]: sending NAK (1, File not found) to 192.168.50.93
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16388]: RRQ from 192.168.50.93 filename /boot/grub/grub.cfg-C0A
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16388]: sending NAK (1, File not found) to 192.168.50.93
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16389]: RRQ from 192.168.50.93 filename /boot/grub/grub.cfg-C0
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16389]: sending NAK (1, File not found) to 192.168.50.93
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16390]: RRQ from 192.168.50.93 filename /boot/grub/grub.cfg-C
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16390]: sending NAK (1, File not found) to 192.168.50.93
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16391]: RRQ from 192.168.50.93 filename /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/command.lst
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16392]: RRQ from 192.168.50.93 filename /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/fs.lst
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16393]: RRQ from 192.168.50.93 filename /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/crypto.lst
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16394]: RRQ from 192.168.50.93 filename /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/terminal.lst
Jun 30 14:25:22 zorn in.tftpd[16395]: RRQ from 192.168.50.93 filename /boot/grub/grub.cfg
...
```

This corresponds with what you can find in the [GRUB manual, Ch 8](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Network.html) - from this I could see that it kept looking for the menu file in `/boot/grub`, and because the tftp daemon is chrooted to its work directory `/srv/tftp`, this path is actually `/srv/tftp/boot/grub`.